# iOS/iPhone ARC memory management

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, null, automatic-ref-counting

```
 __weak NSString *strin = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hey"] ;

    NSLog(@"weak %@",strin); //returns weak (null)

__weak NSString *strin =@"hey";

NSLog(@"weak %@",strin); //returns weak hey
```

What is the difference between both the snippets. Why the second is returning the value when weak is assigned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `@"hey"` is a constant string literal which will be around forever, whereas the weak reference to the first (allocated) string is not enough to keep it alive.

Answer (score 1):

Check below snap and you will get your answer your self.

[image]